# When a mysql database value is null, JTable getValue is not working

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, null

I have a JTable that gets values from mysql and I have a MouseClicked action that when I click a row, it takes the values and writes to the JTextFields. The problem is when mysql value is null, it gives NullPointerException and dosen't write anything to the JTextFields.

It works when they are not null and shows the whole information where I want it. But I want it to write them as a empty JTextFields without error when they are null.

This is my mouseclick action code that only works when selected row's value is not null:

```
 private void calisanTablosuMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    int selectedrow = calisanTablosu.getSelectedRow();
    alan_adSoyad.setText(calisanTablosu.getValueAt(selectedrow,1).toString());
    }
```

Not very good at English so basic explanation or just the code will be good. Thanks.

Comment: First post your code.

Comment: I don't think I need to post any code for this but ok. I just need to know how to make it empty, not null.

Comment: I assume `selectedrow` is negative when there is no selected row? If so why are you not checking it before executing the next row?

Comment: No it works like this: You select a row. It takes the values at colums and writes to JTextFields. But when I select a row and if the any of the colums are empty, it gives NullPointerException.

Comment: Okay I got the problem. Looks like I write one of the objects wrong and it wasn't reading it. Thanks for help.